# http://localhost:9876/assets/i18n/en.json 404 ng2-translate

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-translate

I am trying to run a simple unit test on angular2 app generated with angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.14 which uses ng2-translate@2.5.0.

When I run my unit tests the translate service can not load the translation file.

I believe the solution lies in a combination of karma.conf proxies property, the TranslateStaticLoader and the angular-cli.json setup.

I am using the standard cli directory structure. I have a feeling/hope this is a common problem. Will provide code and directory snippets if needed.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote unit test with ng2-translate and I did it as the following example:

beforeEach(() => {

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceMock },
    { provide: TranslatePipe, useClass: TranslatePipe },
  ],

  imports: [TranslateModule]
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I did what you suggested but I can't figure out how to get mock service class to return a value. Below is my mock class. Could you show me yours? :)

`class TranslateServiceMock {
  setDefaultLang () {

  }

  use (e) {
    console.log('translating', e, en);
  }
}`

Comment: My mock look like this: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class TranslateServiceMock {
    addLangs(langs: Array<string>) {

    }

    setDefaultLang(lang: string) {

    }

    use(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        return null;
    }
}